# "Precedente" versus "previo"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Qual è la differenza tra "precedente" e "previo"? In un colloquio di lavoro, ad esempio, è corretto dire

> "Quali sono le sue esperienze di lavoro *previe*?"

oppure si dovrebbe dire

> "Quali sono le sue esperienze di lavoro *precedenti*?"

Comment: L'aggettivo "previo" si usa normalmente in contesti burocratici per indicare condizioni necessarie. Si può forse usare negli annunci di giornale, per risparmiare in numero di caratteri, altrimenti eviterei di usarlo.

Comment: Quell'utilizzo di *previo* suona malissimo. Non è un termine di uso comune, se non, come già detto, in contesti dove si vuole indicare condizioni necessarie (*La tessera verrà rilasciata previo pagamento di euro 25 ...*). Nel parlato non si usa *mai*.

Comment: Per curiosità, ecco che cosa ne pensa Ngram Viewer: http://tinyurl.com/nkoyrud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In generale, *previo* ha un utilizzo diverso. Lo si trova spesso in forme come *previo accordo*, *previo consenso*, *previo pagamento*, nel significato di "a condizione che". Ad esempio:

> "*Agiremo previo consenso dell'interessato*" è un classico esempio per questa frase, che si potrebbe trovare in un contratto e in genere in documenti legali. Significa "a condizione che l'interessato ci dia il consenso, noi agiremo"; "agiremo, solo se l'interessato ci darà il consenso".

*Previo* letteralmente significa "precedente", ma viene usato solo in contesti burocratici (nei testi scritti più che nelle comunicazioni orali) o negli avvisi sui giornali. Utilizzarlo in contesti diversi susciterebbe perplessità nell'interlocutore, a causa dell'inusuale formalità della parola; è d'obbligo usare *precedente*.

Per rispondere specificamente alla tua domanda, un colloquio di lavoro non rientra nei "contesti burocratici" citati prima, quindi è opportuno usare *precedenti*.

Answer (score 3):

*previo* non può essere usato con funzione predicativa.
Si puo usare davanti a un sostantivo in quella che si chiama *costruzione assoluta*, che richiama il classico *ablativo assoluto* (in latino)

Si può dunque dire "le mie precedenti esperienze" o "le mie esperienze precedenti",
ma non "le mie previe esperienze" e sopratutto non "*le mie esperenze previe"*

"**previo** pagamento della tassa di soggiorno", significa :" **essendo avvenuto/ dopo che sia stato effettuato** il pagamento...."

Come notato, questo appartiene al linguaggio della burocrazia, ma può essere usato in maniera scherzosa o ironica

Comment: Credo che la domanda vertesse più sul registro della parola, come segnalato dal tag [tag:word-choice], che non sulla sintassi.